# Objective C GameCenter authenticateHandler error

Tags: ios, objective-c, gamekit

I createed a game using [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/60980/game-center-tutorial-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-sprite-kit-part-1). When I call `authenticateLocalPlayer` like so:

```
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

localPlayer.authenticateHandler  =
^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error) {

    [self setLastError:error];
    if(viewController != nil) {
        [self setAuthenticationViewController:viewController];
    } else if([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated) {
        _enableGameCenter = YES;
    } else {
        _enableGameCenter = NO;
    }
};
```

I get an error:

```
-[GKUnauthenticatedPlayerInternal name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14517e00
```

but when I add `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1]` like this:

```
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
localPlayer.authenticateHandler  =
^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error) {

    [self setLastError:error];
    if(viewController != nil) {
        [self setAuthenticationViewController:viewController];
    } else if([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated) {
        _enableGameCenter = YES;
    } else {
        _enableGameCenter = NO;
    }
};
```

It starts working fine.  Is this the correct way to solve the error?

Comment: The NSThread hack does not work for me. Did you ever find any more information about this, or possibly a better hack for it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the very same problem. And a random sleep doesn't solve it for me.

I find it strange that I can't find any other reference to this problem on the internet. We can not be the only people having this problem, can we?

Comment: I only realized that my game had this issue recently. Don't know the source of it either. I will come back when (if?) I get back from the other side!

Comment: So I discovered that the call comes from the line `localPlayer.authenicateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error) {}`. This occurs *even when the block is empty*.

Comment: Yes, I discovered that too. And that seems to be Apple's recommended way to do it. So I wonder how everyone else is doing this?

Comment: This has only been a recent issue for me with one of my games. It seems like it's a Game Center bug. Anyone find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that what triggered the crash for me was a call to 
`[self performSelector: @selector(showLabel) withObject: nil afterDelay: 5]`, 
where self is a SKSpriteNode. Note that it was not the moment when the selector was called but at the very call to performSelector, that I got the crash. Also note that the call had nothing at all to do with GKLocalPlayer or Game Center at all.

What solved the problem was to use SKAction instead, like this:

```
[self runAction:
       [SKAction sequence: @[[SKAction waitForDuration:5],
                             [SKAction performSelector: @selector(showLabel) onTarget: self]]]];
```

I can't really explain why this does the trick. It seems to be a not too obvious bug with iOS 8.1, since this has never been a problem before.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the trick is to not call to initiate Game Center from viewDidLoad. If you do call it from there, call it after a delay. Agreed that this is broken in iOS 8.1 and 8.1.1 because it was never an issue before.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is an issue with iOS 8.0-8.2. It appears to be resolved in iOS 8.3 in my experimentation. Strangely enough, my other game's code base seems to work consistently throughout (I haven't done exhaustive testing though).